# TYPO3 Routing: How to use constants in config.yaml?

Tags: yaml, typo3

**1. Can I use constants in config.yaml files?**

Here's a old, closed feature request: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/81593

**2. What's the best way to realize little differences in routing config.yaml files?** 
For Example:

```
rootPageId: <DEV-ID>
rootPageId: <PROD-ID>
```

With Typoscript this where easy with constants: 
`rootPageId: {$mainTemplate.rootPageId}`

**3. Why is it not possible to use the much better and more flexible TypoScript to do the routing-config with TYPO3 LTS-9?**

**4. Is there a "Backend yaml-Object-Browser" similar to the very good "TypoScript-Object Browser"?**

Answer (score 0):

ad 1) https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/UsingEnvVars.html might be the direction you want to follow

ad 2) why should a rootPageId differ by context? Perhaps the domain could/should differ, but the IDs should probably be the same, example: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/BaseVariants.html

ad 3) I don't understand why a "why" is interesting - You can propose a feature request. However from my experience I didn't ever see a need for that. It is the other way around, probably you want to get site config from TypoScript: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/UseSiteInTypoScript.html

ad 4) That one and UserTSconfig have no browser/viewer atm. Although it shouldn't be hard to implement one.